# PyCharm: Is there a way to make the "data view" auto update when dataframe is changed?

Tags: python, pycharm

When you select "View as DataFrame" in the variables pane it has a nice spreadsheet like view of the DataFrame. That said, as the DataFrame itself changes, the Data View does not auto update and you need to reclick the View as DataFrame to see it again. Is there a way to make PyCharm autoupdate this? Seems like such a basic feature.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a way to do this?

Comment: Sadly, no. Opened a feature request with JetBrains but nothing so far.

Comment: @k-war can you share the feature request? I'd like to +1 it.

Answer (score 4):

If you put a cursor on the text field just below the displayed dataframe and hit Enter, it'll update itself.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no. The only thing you can do is use 'watches' to watch the variable and open when you want it. It requires a lot of background processing and memory usage to display the dataframe.

Comment: Thanks. I opened a feature request with JetBrains so maybe one day. Lots of other IDEs do this, e.g.  MathWorks MATLAB.

Comment: I think Anaconda Spyder had that functionality, and it is far better if you are trying to use python scientific.